# Revenuecat products are null while testing and trying to design paywall

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

Trying to design the paywall following the example flutter app provided by RevenueCat and when I configure the offering are always null.

Running version purchases_flutter: ^1.1.1

Offerings.current = NULL <- this is my problem.

In Google console the app ids are: com.sampleapp.moments.1month, com.sampleapp.moments.yearly and are both active.

How can I go about testing and designing a paywall page if the offerings are null? How can I get this to work?

Error code, following the example: https://github.com/RevenueCat/purchases-flutter/blob/develop/example/lib/main.dart

```
[        ] D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(14481): Requesting products with identifiers: com.sampleapp.moments.1month, com.appname.moments.yearly
[  +82 ms] D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(14481): Products request finished for com.sampleapp.moments.1month, com.sampleapp.moments.yearly
[        ] D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(14481): Retrieved skuDetailsList: 
[        ] D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(14481): Requesting products with identifiers: com.sampleapp.moments.1month, com.sampleapp.moments.yearly
[        ] D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(14481): Products request finished for com.sampleapp.moments.1month, com.sampleapp.moments.yearly
[        ] D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(14481): Retrieved skuDetailsList: 
[+3804 ms] D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(14481): Vending purchaserInfo from cache
[  +99 ms] D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(14481): Vending offerings from cache
```

Comment: I have same issue, Have you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 4):

If your products, offerings, or packages are empty it's most likely related to a configuration or setup issue in Apple/Google.

On Android, you need to **publish** your app to a closed track before you can fetch any products or test purchases - that could be what's going on here.

There is a a handy guide here that outlines the common reasons for this here: https://support.revenuecat.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041793174-Why-are-my-products-offerings-or-available-packages-empty-

Comment: Actually `closed` track  is not required to fetch products - `internal` is enough. But for testing purchase you really need `closed`